# What is the background on this painting that appears in both Angel Beats! and Charlotte?

Tags: angel-beats, charlotte

It is well known that *Charlotte* is the second anime created by Key in collaboration with P.A.Works, the first being *Angel Beats!*. Therefore, it comes as no surprise that *Charlotte* makes passing references to *Angel Beats!*, most of which can be found in episode 7.

This is the scene at 08:19 of episode 10 of *Charlotte*:

[image: School principal and painting]

The painting behind the school principal is the same as the [painting](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/15395/8486) hanging in the Anti-Angel Headquarters in *Angel Beats!*.

This piqued my interest: has this painting appeared in any other fictional work? Is it based on a real-world painting, or is it an original created specifically for the anime? What is the title of the painting and what does it depict? Basically any background information about the painting is much appreciated.